# Drawing a simple 4 box flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts, smartdiagram

I know it is not good to ask this question. But I am out of time and idea how should I start? My supervisor ask me to use LaTeX than document for this figure below which I had draw in .doc file.

[image]

The words/colour inside the box is not important.
The important is how to have a little words on top of the box.

[image]

I also hope I can edit the content as below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tikz` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt and 7pt,
  start chain = A going right,
  box/.style = {draw=blue, fill= blue!30, text width=24mm, minimum height=13mm,
                on chain=A, join=by {-, ultra thick, draw=blue}}
                        ]
  \node[box] {xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx};               % node name: A-1
  \node[box] {xxx xxx xxx xxx  xxx xxx xxx xx};
  \node[box] {xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xx};
  \node[box] {xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xx}; % A-4
%
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
\node[above right=0pt of A-\i.north west, font=\footnotesize] {Experiment \i};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

for your new demand you need slightly to change loop for writing label above nodes:

```
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {Pilot stydy, Study 1, Experiment 2, Feasibile 21}
\node[above right=0pt of A-\j.north west, font=\footnotesize] {\i};
```

using it, you will get:

[image]

Comment: I am so sorry. If I want to make the `Experiment 1, Experiment 2, Experitment 3, Experiment 4` into `Pilot Study, Case 1, Experiment 2, Ex 3`. Is it possible? I have a look at `\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
\node[above right=0pt of A-\i.north west, font=\footnotesize] {Experiment \i};`. But hard to change this

Comment: @ann, sorry, I don't understand you. Please edit your question and show us a sketch, what you like to have. I just reproduce your image.

Comment: no need to apologies, my bad English explanation. I had added in a diagram in my questions. So sorry for your time.

Comment: @ann, it is not problem of English ... however, one sketch = 1000 words. As I now see, you only like replace names "experiments ..." with "Pilot study", etc. I add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Brillant!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution by using normal `tabular` environment,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{5pc}p{5pc}p{5pc}p{5pc}}
Experiment 1 &Experiment 2 &Experiment 3 &Experiment 4\\
\colorbox{blue!10}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}}
&\multicolumn{1}{@{{\color{blue!10}\rule{1pc}{3pt}}}l@{}}{\colorbox{blue!10}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{@{{\color{blue!10}\rule{1pc}{3pt}}}l@{}}{\colorbox{blue!10}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}}} &\multicolumn{1}{@{{\color{blue!10}\rule{1pc}{3pt}}}l}{\colorbox{blue!10}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}} }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{3pt}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{5pc}p{5pc}p{5pc}p{5pc}}
Experiment 1 &Experiment 2 &Experiment 3 &Experiment 4\\
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}}
&\multicolumn{1}{@{\hskip3pt{\color{black}\rule{1pc}{3pt}}}l@{}}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}}}
&\multicolumn{1}{@{{\color{black}\rule{1pc}{3pt}}}l@{}}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}}} &\multicolumn{1}{@{{\color{black}\rule{1pc}{3pt}}}l}{\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\parbox{5pc}{
System examination, user epxerience}} }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to add a border of each box? I want the box colour is white, so, `\colorbox{white}`. But how to add a black border?

Comment: @aan Refer the edited suggestion...

Comment: thanks. can you check again, it very different from my output here. Maybe is my setting in preample